# How to display unselected option data in real time on the use of add more in laravel

Tags: jquery, mysql, arrays, ajax, laravel

i have a form input with add more button. when, user want to add more input section, he can click add more button. In my form input, i have form input type select option with some option.

My form input

[My Form Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAjGa.png)

My problem is i want show unselected option in real time

Example :

1. In the form input index 0, I chose the palette code G05B-IA1
2. In the input index of form 1, I selected the palette code G05B-IA2, and at index 1, the palette code G05B-IA1 doesn't appear because it has been selected at index 0.
3. And at index 2, the code palette G05B-IA1 and G05B-IA2 do not appear because they have been selected at index 0 and 1. Then, at index 2 I choose G05B-IA3
4. Then, at index 4, which does not appear only the code palette G05B-IA1 and G05B-IA3. The code palette G05B-IA2 appears at the 4th index. My error was that I accommodated in the array only [index 0 and index[i] ] *i was the number of sections of the input form

My form input code index 0

```
      <div class="add-more-pallet">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Pilih Gudang : </label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control" id="warehouse" required>
                        <option value="">-- Pilih Gudang --</option>
                        @foreach($warehouse as $row)
                        <option value="{{ $row->id_warehouse }}">{{ $row->warehouse_name }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                   </select>
                </div>
            </div>
          <div class="col-md-5">
                <label>Pilih Pallet : </label>
                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-pallet"></i></span>
                    </div>
                    <select class="form-control" id="slot_id" name="slot_id[]" required><option value="">-- Pilih Pallet --</option></select>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My jquery code for showing data pallet index 0

```
  $('#warehouse').change(function(){
      var warehouseid = $(this).val(); 
      if(warehouseid){
          $.ajax({
              type:"GET",
              url:"/admin-user/get_slot_id?warehouseid="+warehouseid,
              dataType: 'JSON',
              success:function(res){        
              if(res){
                  $("#slot_id").empty();
                  $("#slot_id").append('<option value="">-- Pilih Pallet --</option>');
                  $.each(res,function(id_slot,id_slot){
                      $("#slot_id").append(
                        '<option value="'+id_slot+'">'+id_slot+'</option>'
                      );
                  });
              }else{
                     $("#slot_id").empty();
              }
              }
          });
      }else{
              $("#slot_id").empty();
      }      
  });
```

My form input code index 1 and so on

```
'<div class="col-md-6">' + 
                        '<label>Pilih Gudang : </label>' +
                        '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
                          '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                            '<span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-warehouse"></i></span>' +
                          '</div>' +
                          '<select class="form-control warehouse2" data-idtarget="'+i+'" required>' +
                            '<option value="">-- Pilih Gudang --</option>' +
                            '<option value="G05B">Gudang 05 B</option>' +
                            '<option value="G09">Gudang 09</option>' +
                          '</select>' +
                        '</div>' +
                      '</div>' +
                      '<div class="col-md-5">' + 
                        '<label>Pilih Pallet : </label>' +
                        '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
                          '<div class="input-group-prepend">' +
                            '<span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-pallet"></i></span>' +
                          '</div>' +
                          '<select id="slot_id'+i+'" class="form-control" name="slot_id['+i+']" data-idtarget="'+i+'" required><option value="">-- Pilih Pallet --</option></select>' +
                        '</div>' +
                      '</div>' +
```

My jquery code for showing data pallet index 1 and so on

```
  $(document).on('change', '.warehouse2', function(){
      var warehouseid = $(this).val(); 
      let idtarget  = $(this).data('idtarget');
      let cektarget = idtarget - 1;
      let slotid1   = $("#slot_id").val();
      let slotid2   = $("#slot_id"+cektarget+'').val();
      let data      = [slotid1, slotid2];
      console.log(data);
      if(warehouseid){
          $.ajax({
              type:"GET",
              url:"/admin-user/get_slot_id_not_in?warehouseid="+warehouseid,
              data:{"data":data},
              dataType: 'JSON',
              success:function(res){             
              if(res){
                  $("#slot_id" + idtarget).empty();
                  $("#slot_id" + idtarget).append('<option>---Pilih Pallet---</option>');
                  $.each(res,function(id_slot,id_slot){
                      $("#slot_id" + idtarget).append(
                        '<option value="'+id_slot+'">'+id_slot+'</option>'
                      );
                  });
              }else{
                     $("#slot_id" + idtarget).empty();
              }
              }
          });
      }else{
              $("#slot_id" + idtarget).empty();
      }      
  });
```

My Controller

```
public function getSlotIdNotIn(Request $request)
{
    $slotid = DB::table('tbl_slots')->where('warehouse_id', $request->warehouseid)
              ->where('slot_status','Tersedia')
              ->whereNotIn('id_slot', $request->data)
              ->pluck('id_slot','id_slot');
    return response()->json($slotid);

}
```

It can be seen that I only hold 2 slot ids in one array, for slotid 1 for index 0, and slotid 2 for index 1 and so on

```
var warehouseid = $(this).val(); 
          let idtarget  = $(this).data('idtarget');
          let cektarget = idtarget - 1;
          let slotid1   = $("#slot_id").val();
          let slotid2   = $("#slot_id"+cektarget+'').val();
          let data      = [slotid1, slotid2];
```

My question is how to add the data slot id of each index into the array, so that the array can accommodate the slot id of each index that has been selected.

Answer (score 0):

Place that under your events and use function `optionsFor` with input id argument (numeric, first - 0, second - 1...). This function return array of slot ids, that can be selected. And with this array you can render options for input.

```js
let options = []; // store your slot ids
let selected = []; // store your selected id target for each input (first value for first input, second value for second input...)

function optionsFor(inputId) {
  return options.filter(x => inputId < selected.length && selected[inputId] === x || selected.find(y => y === x) === undefined);
}
```

On change value just rerender your options on each input.